# Black screen in Kubuntu (but not in Ubuntu) after installing Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu

I get a black screen after installing Nvidia drivers in Kubuntu. But if I try to install it in Ubuntu, it is OK.

- Laptop: Lenovo g50-30
- Video: Intel HD Graphics and Nvidia 820m
- Distro versions: 20.04

[image: output of lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display' in TTY]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109955/discussion-on-question-by--black-screen-in-kubuntu-after-nvidia-drivers-ins).